# Simple facebook API query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I am trying to do the simplest thing in the world: I want a node script to fetch the PUBLIC feed of a page.

I am trying with this:

```
var FB = require('fb' )

FB.api('/flourandfire/feed', 'get', function (res) {
  if (!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error)
    return
  }
  console.log(res.id)
  console.log(res.name)
})
```

And it's not working.

```
{ message: 'An access token is required to request this resource.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 104,
  fbtrace_id: 'EiH31CMsyvh' }
```

So, I created an "app" by the same user who owns the page and tried:

```
var FB = require('fb', { appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', appSecret: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' })

FB.api('/flourandfire/feed', 'get', function (res) {
  if (!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error)
    return
  }
  console.log(res.id)
  console.log(res.name)That is, what's the EASIEST, most permanent way to get the right access token/appId/appSecret/whatever to plumb into these functions and make the call work?That is, what's the EASIEST, most permanent way to get the right access token/appId/appSecret/whatever to plumb into these functions and mThat is, what's the EASIEST, most permanent way to get the right access token/appId/appSecret/whatever to plumb into these functions and make the call work?ake the call work?That is, what's the EASIEST, most permanent way to get the right access token/appId/appSecret/whatever to plumb into these functions and make the call work?
})
```

Still nothing.

```
{ message: 'An access token is required to request this resource.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 104,
  fbtrace_id: 'EiH31CMsyvh' }
```

I tried adding the access token for that app:

```
var FB = require('fb', { appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', appSecret: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' })

FB.api('/flourandfire/feed', 'get', { access_token: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' }, function (res) {
  if (!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error)
    return
  }
  console.log(res.id)
  console.log(res.name)
})
```

Still nothing:

```
{ message: 'Invalid OAuth access token.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 190,
  fbtrace_id: 'Hf8Gjudpwty' }
```

The feed is public.
So, how the HECK do I get this feed?

That is, what's the EASIEST, most permanent way to get the right access token/appId/appSecret/whatever to plumb into these functions and make the call work?

Comment: Provide a _valid_ token then, instead of in invalid one ...? If the page is public and the posts are not targeted to specific audience, then the app access token will do. And that, in its simplest form, if the combination of app id and app secret with a pipe symbol in between.

Comment: This actually fixed it. Can you set it as the answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: that is actually what my answer says...it tells you how an app access token looks like. you can also read about that (and other forms of tokens) in the links in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve never used the fb package, but the docs tell me that this should work:

```
var FB = require('fb');
FB.options({appId: 'xxx', appSecret: 'xxx'});
FB.setAccessToken('APP-ID|APP-SECRET'); //btw, this is an "App Access Token". Maybe you do not even need this line if you specify the options correctly.
//FB.options({accessToken: 'APP-ID|APP-SECRET'}); //another way according to the docs

FB.api('/flourandfire/feed', (res) => {
  if (!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(res);
});
```

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/